# Inner product of hermitian conjugate identity in QM

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators, adjoint-functors

Could someone kindly show me why

$\left \langle f \mid \hat{A} \mid g\right \rangle=\left \langle f \mid \hat{A}g \right \rangle =\int dxf^{*}\left ( \hat{A}g \right )
=\int dx \left ( \hat{A^{\dagger}f}^{} \right )^{*}g
=\left \langle \hat{A^{\dagger}f} \mid g \right \rangle$

I do not understand the second last equivalence despite looking at it for a while. It doesn't make sense to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the star means conjugate and the dagger means conjugate transpose right? (I'm often confused these between math and physics...

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Isn't this just the meaning of adjoint operators? Or I missed anything?

Comment: I am unable to see the equivalence.

Comment: Why does the dagger appear in the second last integral? This is very frustrating.
The rules for self-adjoint is <Ax,y>=<x,Ay> for any x,y in H and operator A.

Comment: Oh,...I'm not sure if it is correct... isn't the adjoint of $\hat{A}$ the such operator that the following equation holds: $\left \langle f \mid \hat{A}g \right \rangle=\left \langle \hat{A^{\dagger}f} \mid g \right \rangle ?$

Comment: @tommyxu3
Wikipedia is singing a different tune.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint

Comment: different? Doesn't it also say <Ax, y> = <x, adj(A)y>??

Comment: Under section "Hermitian Operators"

Comment: Ok,... I'm not familiar with physics convention and don't know the hat means it is self-adjoint... sorry no help (but if so, then $\hat{A}=\hat{A^{\dagger}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the necessary relationship that *defines* the hermitian conjugate operator $\hat{A^{\dagger}}$.

In other words the question is, if I operate on $g$ with $\hat{A}$ then what do I have to operate on $f$ with to get the same integral? This is new operator is given the symbol $\hat{A^{\dagger}}$ and named hermitian conjugate.

If it turns out that $\hat{A^{\dagger}} = \hat{A}$ then $\hat{A}$ is self-adjoint or hermitian.

For further reassurance see Equation (3.2) [here](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_operator.pdf)

Comment: I see the definition in the link you provided. Thanks for that.
However, my intuition tells me that there could be a proof to this and the 'shuffling' of the variables might hint the operator are matrices.